# How do you replace a Moen cartridge 4000?

Tags: faucet, replacement, kitchen-sink, cartridge

Recently my kitchen faucet delivers less water pressure for hot water (cold water is fine) and water takes much longer to get warm. All other faucets (bathroom sinks, shower, ...) are working as usual.

By doing some research I learned that this problem may be caused by a clogged aerator, and that I might need to replace the faucet's cartridge (I already tried cleaning the O-ring and screen washer kit and did not fix the problem).

It seems that my faucet's model is a [Moen Kleo](https://www.moen.com/shared/docs/exploded-parts-views/ca87011pt.pdf) and might have a cartridge #1255 or #4000 (Based on looks after removing handle it could be the cartridge #4000). I took the handle out with an allen key, but I can't take out the cartridge. It is too hard to yank out and I'm afraid to break something. I can't take the dome piece out either (in case I needed to do this first and then unscrew the cartridge piece). It is too hard. Since the [installation guide](https://www.moen.com/shared/docs/instruction-sheets/ins10205a.pdf) refers to the faucet as "faucet body" and does not cover cartridge replacement I don't know if I should be able to unscrew or yank out the dome (and I don't want to force and break anything).

I have been able to find tutorials on youtube, but not for my specific cartridge (or faucet model), so I don't know what to do about those pieces. 
[Home depot's Q&A](http://www.homedepot.com/p/MOEN-Kleo-Single-Handle-Pull-Down-Sprayer-Kitchen-Faucet-Featuring-Reflex-in-Spot-Resist-Stainless-CA87011SRS/202497879) doesn't cover this specific question, as neither does [Moen's](http://www.moen.com/kleo/spot-resist-stainless-one-handle-high-arc-pulldown-kitchen-faucet/_/R-CONSUMER%3ACA87011SRS?next=SiteSearch.Image%7CPDP).

Still, the cartridge replacement can be found in their websites (among others) which makes me think I should not need a professional to replace it. I am not the first owner of this place, so I don't have the original installation tools, in case any is needed to take one of the pieces out.

What is the process to replace a Moen Cartridge 4000 in a Moen Kleo Faucet?

Comment: Also see: https://solutions.moen.com/Article_Library/4000%2F%2F40002_Cartridge%3A_Kitchen_Faucet

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Moen has an outstanding customer support, and after emailing them a couple pictures of my faucet to confirm the model they emailed me back instructions to replace the cartridge (along with a confirmation of the cartridge my model was using).

S o basically:

1. Turn water supply off
2. Use an allen wrench to remove the faucet's handle
3. Grab the collar and rotate counter-clockwise.
4. Using large pliers or channel locks remove the retainer counter-clock wise
5. Using pliers grab the white square of the cartridge and remove it from the faucet.

Documentation says that your bare hands should be enough for step #3. This was one of my problems I wasn't sure if I was going to need any tools. It seems that rotating should be enough and force can be applied.

To install the new cartridge you need to pay attention to the cartridge's 3 holes and 2 small tabs protruding. You need to look into the brass chamber to find the location of the 3 big and 2 smaller holes, align the cartridge and insert it making sure you are lining up the three big holes.

Gentle pressure should be able to rotate the cartridge.

After making sure that the cartridge is positioned correctly, you reassemble the faucet.